# Adding vertical lines to 3D gnuplot graph

Tags: gnuplot

In the following trivial 3D gnuplot scatter graph, there are two points (labeled A and B). Unfortunately, since this there is no logical connection between the points, it's impossible to tell visually where these points lie in the 3D space.

[image: Original graph]

The way I would prefer to remedy this is to add vertical lines on the Z axis down to the Z = 0 floor plane, something like the following blue lines (color irrelevant) which I slapped on with MS Paint to illustrate what I want:

[image: Same graph with vertical lines added]

This way it's easy to see, for example, that A is higher than B. After some searching, I haven't been able to dig up anything on how to implement this with gnuplot. I would greatly appreciate any assistance whether it's an RTFM pointer, or existing example of how to implement this type of plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Murphy's Law, I finally stumbled upon the answer right after posting the question. The trick is to use `with impulses` in the `splot` graph definition, and then re-plot the same series `with points` to get crosses on top of the impulse lines. Here's the (somewhat stylized) result:

[image: Final graph]

For example's sake, below is the full gnuplot script I used to generate the above, although as mentioned, the `splot` line at the end `with impulses` and `with points` is the necessary bit to answer the question.

```gnuplot
set object rect from screen 0, screen 0 to screen 1, \
           screen 1 fillcolor rgb "black" fillstyle solid 0.9 behind
set grid xtics ytics ztics mytics \
         linetype 3 linewidth 0 linecolor rgb "#3366aa", \
         linetype 3 linewidth 0 linecolor rgb "#3366aa"
set terminal postscript enhanced color size 10,4.9
set output "/path/to/graph.png"
set border linecolor rgb "#3366aa"
set xyplane 0

 splot '/path/to/data' title "" with impulses linecolor rgb "#556600", \
       '/path/to/data' title "" with points   linecolor rgb "#eeff66"
```